# Navigation from drawer in react native router flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have used [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) for navigation in react app. I've implemented Drawer in routes.

Here is my

**Routes.js**

```
<Router>

    <Scene key="app" hideNavBar={true} initial={this.props.isLoggedIn}>

        <Drawer key="drawer" drawer={true} contentComponent={SideMenu} initial={true}>
                 <Scene key="homeScreen" component={HomeScreen} hideNavBar={false} navBar={() => <HeaderDrawer title="Home" />} />
                 <Scene key="paymentScreen" component={PaymentScreen} hideNavBar={false} navBar={() => <HeaderDrawer title="Payment" />} />
                 <Scene key="activityScreen" component={ActivityStatement} hieNavBar={false} navBar={() => <HeaderDrawer title="Activity Statements" />} />
         </Drawer>

        <Scene key="forgotPassword" hideNavBar={false} component={ForgotPasswordScreen} navBar={() => <Header title="Forgot Password" />} />

    </Scene>

<Router>
```

Now, I can able to move from one of the drawer tab to `forgotPassword` using `Actions.forgotPassword()` but from `forgotPassword` I'm not able to come back to drawer using `Actions.pop()`. Can anybody tell what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```js
openDrawer = () => {
    Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: true });
}
```

```js
<Scene key="forgotPassword" hideNavBar={false} component={ForgotPasswordScreen} navBar={() => <Header title="Forgot Password" />} back={true} onBack={this.openDrawer} />
```